# Trouble installing libc-dev

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, c, gcc

I am getting this error when I try to compile a C program on Ubuntu:

```
$ gcc aa.c
aa.c:1:9: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include<stdio.h>
         ^--------
compilation terminated.
```

I tried to install `libc6-dev` and got this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-10 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.27-3ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problelms, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried:
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and I got no output.

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

above four codes got the same output:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

After using all those commands I get the same fatal error when compiling.

```
apt policy libc6-dev libc6
```

o/p:

```
libc6-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.27-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
libc6:
  Installed: 2.29-10
  Candidate: 2.29-10
  Version table:
 *** 2.29-10 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.27-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You are on the correct path. You need to install that library.

Comment: Do you remember where your `libc` 2.29-10 came from, and why you installed it?

Comment: no :( @StephenKitt

Answer (score 1):

You’ve somehow ended up with the current Debian testing version of `libc6`, not any Ubuntu version. Presumably there’s a reason for that, so changing it might break something.

At this point you have two options:

- downgrade `libc6` to the Ubuntu version:

  ```
  sudo apt install libc6=2.27-3ubuntu1
  ```

  which will also require downgrading related packages (`apt` will tell you which ones, but I imagine you’d have at least `libc-bin` and `locales`)

  *or*
- install the Debian testing `libc6-dev` package:

  ```
  wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.29-10_amd64.deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev-bin_2.29-10_amd64.deb
  sudo apt install ./libc6-dev_2.29-10_amd64.deb ./libc6-dev-bin_2.29-10_amd64.deb
  ```

I would recommend reverting to the Ubuntu version, if only to make your next distribution upgrade simpler, but that might have other more immediate consequences.